# Chef template unable to enable service

Tags: ruby, templates, chef-infra

I'm trying to configure SEC (Simple event correlation) on a RH7 with systemd, and I need multiple instances.
I used to do this on RH<7 without systemd, but I'm failing to adapt it to systemd.
I'm using [this trick](http://simple-evcorr.github.io/FAQ.html#21) to run multiple instance :

- I've created a sec@.service file for systemd
- I'm trying to create the options file for this service, using a template :

```
<%-
index = 0
%>
[...]
<%- if ( (node[:platform] == "redhat" &&  node[:platform_version] >= "7")) %>
OPTIONS_<%= index %>="--conf=/etc/sec/oracle.sec --input=/var/log/oracle.log "
<%- else %>
SEC_ARGS[<%= index %>]="-detach -conf=/etc/sec/oracle.sec -input=/var/log/oracle.log -log=/var/log/sec.log -intevents -pid=/var/run/sec<%= index %>.pid"
<%- end %>
<%-
  index = index + 1
%>
```

(You can see the "old" syntax at the bottom, for RH<7)

So, now all the files are presents, and when started manually, with `systemctl start sec@0`, it does the job.

My issue, is that I need to enable the service `sec@0`, but apparently, I'm not allowed to do that in the template file :

```
systemctl enable sec@0
```

So, I'm running out of solution : how can I enable it now ?

EDIT :
This is how I'm creating the systemd service :

```
if ( (node[:platform] == "redhat" &&  node[:platform_version] >= "7"))
  cookbook_file "/usr/lib/systemd/system/sec@.service" do 
    source "usr/lib/systemd/system/sec@.service"
    owner "root"; group "root"; mode "0644"
  end
end
```

And this is how I'm creating the sec config files, which stores all the instances :

```
template "/etc/sysconfig/sec" do
  source "etc/sysconfig/sec.erb"
  owner "root"; group "root"; mode "0644"
  notifies :restart, resources(:service => "sec")
end
```

Would you know a way to "list" all the instances created in the /etc/sysconfig/sec, and enable them after the creation of this file ?

Comment: If you create these files manually, and enable the service with the command, does it work? Also, its not possible to enable the service from template file, if that's what you are trying to do.