# chef : enable service based on a "grep" result

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I had a [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193647/chef-template-unable-to-enable-service), but apparently, I was doing things in the wrong way, so trying this new approach. I'm creating a systemd service file to run multiple instances of the service :

```
if ( (node[:platform] == "redhat" &&  node[:platform_version] >= "7"))
  cookbook_file "/usr/lib/systemd/system/sec@.service" do 
    source "usr/lib/systemd/system/sec@.service"
    owner "root"; group "root"; mode "0644"
  end
end
```

The number of instances (and names) is configured into a file, with one or multiple entries like :

```
OPTIONS_0="--conf=/etc/sec/oracle.sec --input=/var/log/oracle.log "
OPTIONS_1="--conf=/etc/sec/jboss.sec --input=/var/log/jboss.log "
```

Now, I need to enable as many services as OPTIONS_X exist in this file.
As a "bash-man", I would grep, but I suppose there must exist a right way to do this in ruby, so that in the end, it will run :

```
service "sec@0" do action [:enable, :start]  end
service "sec@1" do action [:enable, :start]  end
[...]
service "sec@X" do action [:enable, :start]  end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the basis for the list of services is from a file, bash/shell utilities would be more efficient in getting the required details, i.e. the count of OPTIONS. This also means that this file would need to be maintained/updated correctly for this logic to work.

Something like:

```bash
grep OPTIONS_ path/to/file | wc -l
```

This count can be stored in a variable and services can be enabled/started based on this.

```rb
count = `grep OPTIONS_ path/to/file | wc -l`

count.to_i.times do |num|
  service "sec@#{num}" do
    action [:enable, :start]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read files line by line with ruby using [IO.each_line](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/IO.html#method-i-each_line) or [IO.readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/IO.html#method-i-readlines)

```rb
File.readlines('/path/to/file').count.times do |i|
  service "sec@#{i}" do
    action [:enable, :start]
  end
end
```